# JsPyBridge: PostCss module not working as intended

Tags: javascript, python, tailwind-css, postcss

i am trying to use [postcss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss) with tailwindcss plugin through [JsPyBridge](https://pypi.org/project/javascript/). the nodejs code is working but the python code gives error on the last part `.then`  and giving `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` error

```js
import tailwind from "tailwindcss";
import postcss from "postcss";
postcss([
  tailwind({
    content: [path.join(__dirname, "../app/**/*.*")],
  }),
])
  .process(_input_css, { from: undefined })
  .then((css) => {
    console.log(css.css);
  });
```

```py
from javascript import require

tailwind = require("tailwindcss")
postcss = require("postcss")

postcss([tailwind({"content": [DIR + "../app/**/*.*"]})]).process(
    _input_css, {"from": None}
).then(lambda css: print(css.css))
```